# Is it considered a good practice to use ActiveSupport in non-Rails gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, activesupport

I developed code as a part of big Rails project. Now I want to extract it as a separate script, independent of Rails to share with the community.

It's my first gem, and it might be overkill including Active Support to use the date functions and inflections as part of a relatively small gem.

What would be the best solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a really subjective call. While ActiveSupport does provide a number of useful date manipulation methods, including it just for that is extremely heavy-duty and can cause absolute chaos when included in projects that aren't expecting it. Some features, if enabled, like the auto-loader system, can change how `require` works and how missing classes are handled, in dramatic and unexpected ways.

If you're creating a project that's *probably* going to be paired with Rails or ActiveSupport anyway, it's probably not a big deal. If this is rarely going to be the case, you might want to simply re-implement the date methods in your own module so that there's no dependency.

Keep in mind that ActiveSupport does significant re-decorating to many core classes, so imposing that on people using your gem is perhaps making your gem a rather unruly guest.

There's also few things more annoying than getting stuck in dependency hell where one won't work with ActiveSupport newer than X and another won't work with a version as old as that, meaning there's no singular version that works at all.

Answer (score 4):

ActiveSupport was refactored a while back to make it very convenient to pick and choose the functionality you want.

Check out the [Core-Extensions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) page for more information.

I think it's pretty common for a serious Ruby developer to have Rails and its components already installed. Just don't insist on a specific version of ActiveSupport. Specify the version they started doing the core-extensions as a minimum you need, and it'll be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the source for ActiveSupport (https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport) and extract the classes and/or methods you need.

Comment: But this means that I would have to support and test this extracted functionality, do you think that this might be better than including full activesupport?

Comment: Personally I would just include the gem and know that it is its own self-contained and tested unit to alleviate any concerns and just focus on testing my own code. There's really nothing taboo about that approach.

Comment: Don't do this. Active Support makes it easy to pull in just the parts you need. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html